# MVC3 Url Routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to register a route as follows :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "SaleReport", // Route name
            "SaleReport/GetDataConsolidated/{type}",
            new { controller = "SaleReport", 
                  action = "GetDataConsolidated",
                  type =   UrlParameter.Optional});
```

and in controller

```
public ActionResult GetDataConsolidated(string type)

    {
      return Content("Report Type = " + type);
    }
```

i am calling it like : localhost:56674/SaleReport/GetDataConsolidated/Sale

but the problem is the value of type is always null. 
what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just order of `.MapRoute(...)` calls.

Put your "SaleReport" `.MapRoute(...)` call before "Default" `{controller}/{action}` `.MapRoute(...)` call, since it's more specific.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SaleReport",
        url: "SaleReport/GetDataConsolidated/{type}",
        defaults: new { controller = "SaleReport", action = "GetDataConsolidated", type = UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: i have already done that. default route is defined after sale report.

Comment: I just recreated whole example locally and it works fine. Do you have additional routes before "SalesReport"? You did not change variable name accidentally (type)? This what you described in example so far works.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but i have not changed any thing. its the same

Comment: Check that the controller is named exactly "SaleReportController"

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific need to define another map route?

It should work with default route,

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "SaleReport", // Route name
        "SaleReport/GetDataConsolidated/{type}",
        new { controller = "SaleReport", 
              action = "GetDataConsolidated",
              type =   UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Remove Above route,
Just change action methos like below

```
public ActionResult GetDataConsolidated(string id)

{
  return Content("Report Type = " + id);
}
```

This will work,Thanks.